# Cabal package dependencies are satisfied, but I cannot get cabal test to find them

Tags: haskell, dependencies, cabal

I'm not very experienced with the cabal workflow, so I suspect that the problem that I am having is a simple one. But, I cannot fond a solution.

I have the following dependencies in my cabal file:

```
$ grep tasty  ume.cabal 
  build-depends: base >=4.7 && <4.8, HDBC >=2.4 && <2.5, parsec >=3.1 && <3.2, 
filepath >=1.4 && <1.5,
 HDBC-sqlite3 >=2.3 && <2.4, time >=1.5 && <1.6, sqlite >=0.5 && <0.6, 
bytestring >=0.10 && <0.11, unix >=2.7 && <2.8, cryptohash >=0.11 && <0.12, process >=1.2 && <1.3, 
transformers >= 0.4 && < 0.5, text, base16-bytestring, 
utf8-string, tasty >= 0.11 && < 0.12,tasty-hunit >= 0.9 && < 0.10
```

Ok, when I try to run the test suit, I get this message:

```
$ cabal test
Re-configuring with test suites enabled. If this fails, please run configure
manually.
Resolving dependencies...
Configuring umecore-hs-0.0.1.0...
cabal: At least the following dependencies are missing:
tasty ==0.11.*, tasty-hunit ==0.9.*
```

however, when I try to install the missing packages, I get this message:

```
$ cabal install tasty tasty-hunit
Resolving dependencies...
All the requested packages are already installed:
tasty-0.11.0.1
tasty-hunit-0.9.2
Use --reinstall if you want to reinstall anyway.
```

So, the dependencies are met. How come I am not able to use the libraries?

EDIT:

Here is the whole cabal file:

```
name:                umecore-hs
version:             0.0.1.0
synopsis:            An infrastructure for querying phonetic data
description:         A framwork for takeing transcription files into a database structure, so that phonetically relevant queries may be made on the transcriptions.
homepage:            https://github.com/dargosch/umecore-hs/wiki
license:             BSD3
license-file:        LICENSE
author:              Fredrik Karlsson
maintainer:          fredrik.k.karlsson@umu.se
-- copyright:
category:            Database
build-type:          Simple
-- extra-source-files:
cabal-version:       >=1.10

library
  exposed-modules:     Phonetic.Database.QueryGenerator, Phonetic.Database.SegmentList, Phonetic.Database.UmeDatabase, Phonetic.Database.UmeQuery, Phonetic.IPA.IPAParser, Phonetic.Database.DataTypes, Phonetic.Database.UmeQueryParser, Phonetic.FileParsers.TextgridParser
  ghc-options:    -W -fno-warn-unused-do-bind -i/Users/frkkan96/Documents/src/umecore-hs/src
  -- other-modules:
  -- other-extensions:
  build-depends:       base >=4.8 && < 4.9, HDBC >=2.4 && <2.5, parsec >=3.1 && <3.2, filepath >=1.4 && <1.5, HDBC-sqlite3 >=2.3 && <2.4, time >=1.5 && <1.6, sqlite >=0.5 && <0.6, bytestring >=0.10 && <0.11, unix >=2.7 && <2.8, cryptohash >=0.11 && <0.12, process >=1.2 && <1.3, transformers >= 0.4 && < 0.5, text >= 1.2 && <= 1.3, base16-bytestring >= 0.1.1 && < 1.1.2, utf8-string >= 1 && < 1.1, directory >=1.2 && <1.3, regex-base >= 0.9 && < 1.0, regex-pcre >= 0.94 && < 0.95, regex-base >= 0.93 && < 0.94
  hs-source-dirs:      src
  default-language:    Haskell2010


Executable textgrid_import
  Main-Is:        textgrid_import.hs
  Hs-Source-Dirs: src
--  Other-Modules:  Phonetic.FileParsers.TextgridParser
  default-language:    Haskell2010
  build-depends:       base >=4.8 && <4.9, HDBC >=2.4 && <2.5, parsec >=3.1 && <3.2, filepath >=1.4 && <1.5, HDBC-sqlite3 >=2.3 && <2.4, time >=1.5 && <1.6, sqlite >=0.5 && <0.6, bytestring >=0.10 && <0.11, unix >=2.7 && <2.8, cryptohash >=0.11 && <0.12, process >=1.2 && <1.3, filemanip >=0.3 && < 0.4, directory >=1.2 && <1.3, optparse-applicative >= 0.12 && < 0.13

Executable umequery
  Main-Is:        umequery.hs
  Hs-Source-Dirs: src
  default-language:    Haskell2010
  build-depends:       base >=4.8 && <4.9, HDBC >=2.4 && <2.5, parsec >=3.1 && <3.2, filepath >=1.4 && <1.5, HDBC-sqlite3 >=2.3 && <2.4, time >=1.5 && <1.6, sqlite >=0.5 && <0.6, bytestring >=0.10 && <0.11, unix >=2.7 && <2.8, cryptohash >=0.11 && <0.12, optparse-applicative >= 0.12 && < 0.13, text >= 1.2 && <= 1.3, base16-bytestring >= 0.1.1 && < 1.1.2, utf8-string >= 1 && < 1.1, transformers >= 0.4 && < 0.5, regex-pcre >= 0.94 && < 0.95, regex-base >= 0.93 && < 0.94



source-repository head
  type:     git
  location: git://github.com/dargosch/umecore-hs.git

test-suite test
  default-language:
    Haskell2010
  type:
    exitcode-stdio-1.0
  hs-source-dirs:
    src, tests
  main-is:
    tests.hs
  build-depends: base >=4.7 && <4.8, HDBC >=2.4 && <2.5, parsec >=3.1 && <3.2, filepath >=1.4 && <1.5, HDBC-sqlite3 >=2.3 && <2.4, time >=1.5 && <1.6, sqlite >=0.5 && <0.6, bytestring >=0.10 && <0.11, unix >=2.7 && <2.8, cryptohash >=0.11 && <0.12, process >=1.2 && <1.3, transformers >= 0.4 && < 0.5, text, base16-bytestring, utf8-string, tasty >= 0.11 && < 0.12,tasty-hunit >= 0.9 && < 0.10
```

Comment: Can you provide your cabal file?

Comment: I think I've noticed this problem as well: when you run `cabal install --dependencies-only`, dependencies that only occur in the tests are not installed.

Comment: try `cabal install --enable-tests` followed by `cabal test`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running `cabal install --enable-tests --only-dependencies` should install the dependencies of the test suite.

Comment: I did not know that I had to run "install" before I could run tests, but it works now. Thanks!